# Is there any analog of Grand Central Dispatch in Qt?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I'm looking for some simple async workaround like GCD but in QT, is there any kind of this or only threads and workers?

Comment: For equivalents to `dispatch_sync` and `dispatch_async`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21646467/1329652).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put: what is there in Qt for implementing task-based concurrency?

The feature is called [Qt Concurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html). I recall we were stopped short of using this feature as long as it is the only Qt feature that enables exceptions but the project implementation guidelines were strongly against exceptions. Also there is [Parallel Patterns Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx) to name one if the platform is Windows. You may also find interesting info here: [Microsoft's Parallel Patterns Library: anyone looked to see how hard it'd be to port to POSIX / Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496266/microsofts-parallel-patterns-library-anyone-looked-to-see-how-hard-itd-be-to)